# Lazarus: язык программирования для реализации макросов

Tags: скрипт, lazarus, кроссплатформенность

Какой язык программирования (желательно интерпретируемый) можно встроить в крупный проект на `Lazarus (GTK+)` для реализации макросов? Скорость выполнения не сильно критична. Было бы неплохо, если бы уже был кем-либо реализованный интерфейс языка для `lazarus` - самому писать интерпретатор некогда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Говорят, можно прикрутить Lua - скриптовый язык. И когда то был даже модуль под это дело - pLua. Ссылки на него вроде сохранились только [здесь](http://www.freepascal.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8967).

Ещё есть [luapascal](http://luapascal.luaforge.net/). Датируется он 2007 и почти все ссылки на сайте ведут в 404 комнату. Но есть он на [github](https://github.com/luaforge/luapascal). Думаю, можно брать и пилить под свои нужды.

В свое время, когда мне нужно было похожее, я брал компоненты jvcl - там есть скриптовый паскаль.  С определенными ограничениями, но достаточно хорош.

А для другой задачи я делал свой скриптовый движок. Простенький, но вполне рабочий был. И это абсолютно не сложно:).

Comment: Мне нужна кроссплатформенность - вот в чем дело. Сомневаюсь, что у luapascal она есть. 
>>"А для другой задачи я делал свой скриптовый движок." - может, зальете исходники, если не жалко? У меня сейчас и другие заботы есть.

Comment: какая именно кроссплатформенность нужна? Посмотрите на список поддерживаемых [платформ](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaBinaries).
Сам luapascal не сильно кросплатформенный, но там можно дописать, задел там есть.

А вот тот свой движок не покажу - во первых, это было более 5 лет назад и писался не для меня, а для компании (соответственно, сорцы стащить не было возможности, да и NDA). А во вторых, он был сильно специализированный.

> У меня сейчас и другие заботы есть.

Нужно назвать все своими именами - просто не хочется писать:)))

Comment: Я начал использовать lua (закинул в папку с проектом скачанный liblua52.so), но не могу скомпилировать - /usr/bin/ld (системный линкер) пишет: "cannot find -llua52" - что с этим можно сделать? Гуглить пробовал. Не помогло.

Comment: логично, что не получится. Это же линукс, а Вы с виндовыми привычками. Установите через пакетный менеджер пакет с lua и будет счастье. А качать с интернета сошки и закидывать в папку с проектом... не правильно это.

Comment: да, я только недавно перебрался на линь :) это тоже не помогает - поставил liblua5.2 и liblua5.2-dev . Ничего. pkg-configure сделал.

Comment: 1. убедитесь, что имя so файла правильно записали в сорцах.
2. убедитесь, что код и библиотека имеют одну разрядность - 32 или 64 бит.